# Get Part of Line By Streamreader

Tags: c#

I've got the following `StreamReader`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        String line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (line != null && line.Contains(":"))
            Console.WriteLine(line.Split(':')[1]);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to know how to do is:

How can I extract a part of this line?

> 111033@@Item1@@21@@0@@37@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@1000

I want to get `111033,21,37,1000` and put it in a Textbox like this

```
textbox_1 = 111033 etc.
```

Comment: Is the format of the line always like that?

Comment: Yup i got about 3000 Line SameFormat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the commercial at characters (@) are separators that separate the line into columns. If the parts you need are always in the same columns, you know their indexes. Therefore start by splitting the line at the separators and take the columns you are interested in:

```
string[] parts = line.Split('@');
textBox_1 = part[0]; // 111033
textBox_2 = part[4]; // 21
textbox_3 = part[8]; // 37
...
```

---

What do these lines represent? Since I don't know, I just take a person’s address as an example (it is probably not the case here, but this is not important).

Create a class that can store your objects. (I did not include validity tests for the sake of simplicity.)

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public static Addess FromLine(string line)
    {
        var a = new Address();

        string[] parts = line.Split('@');

        a.ID = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
        a.FirstName = parts[3];
        a.LastName = parts[4];
        a.City = parts[8];
        return a;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}, {3}", FirstName, LastName, City);
    }
}
```

Now you can add these objects to the combo box. They will automatically be displayed according to the `ToString` method. You can get the selected item with

```
Address a = (Address)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

---

You can fill the combo box like this

```
var items = new List<Address>();
while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    if (line != null && line.Contains("@")) {
        Address a = Address.FromLine(line);
        items.Add(a);
    }
}
myComboBox.DataSource = items;
```

Comment: Worked for me But Not For all Lines And not in same Order Can i Enter Parts[0] in combobox and show whole line where line start with combobox.text?

Comment: The crucial question is what is the selection criterion for the parts that you want to display? Are they always at the same positions (in the same columns) or do you always want to display numbers that are not zero, independently of their position? Please specify!

Comment: i want this Part's
0int,1string,4,37
0 maybe in combo box and show 1,4,37 in textbox's based on Combobox Coz i Have line Full of @@ so hard to find any thing 
ex:5060720@@Cobra@@0@@0@@140@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@3000@@3000@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@1@@1@@0@@0@@0@@601@@4@@0@@1@@0@@0@@1@@800@@0@@0@@1@@900000000@@0@@0@@1000@@0@@0@@0@@0@@300@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@Soul@@Text here@@9@@6@@30@@0@@12000@@500@@

Comment: i wanna Load Parts[0] in combobox.items 
then when i select item from combobox text box's get this part's 1,4,37 based on line start with combobox.text sorry english not my 1st lang

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null && line.Contains(":"))
                    {
                       line.Split(new [] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                              .Where(x => !x.Any(c => char.IsLetter(c)))
                              .ToList()
                              .ForEach( (ln) => Console.WriteLine(ln) );

                    }
                }
            }
```

That will write all numbers to the console.Also you can make it shorter like this:

```
 line.Split(new [] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Where(x => !x.Any(char.IsLetter))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```